# Configuring Springboot security, permitted path(s) not authorised 401

Tags: java, spring-boot, frameworks, authorization

I have a Springboot REST API which has the endpoints

- `/api/quizzes` `GET`
- `/api/quizzes/{id}` `POST`
- `/api/register` `POST`
- `/` `GET` which is a welcome page managed by a Thymeleaf controller class

I have set up my security class as follows;

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /* This sets up the security on specified paths according to role of client */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/quizzes/**").hasRole("USER")
//                .antMatchers("/api/register/").permitAll() // have tried this, still 401
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() // does not permit `/api/register` but does `/` and `h2- 
                                                // console
                .and().headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    /* This sets up the user roles by searching the database for a match, so they can access the 
    endpoints configured above */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Now when I try to access `/api/register` in Postman the response is `401 unauthorised`. I can access `/`. I understood that `/**` is a wildcard for this directory and any subdirectories, so it should match root and `/api/register`, and `permitAll()`?

Edit: Some more info

- comment out all the code in `SecurityConfig`, I get access to `/`, `/api/quizzes`, `/api/quizzes/{id}` but not `/api/register`, in fact it returns 403 instead of 401 which is interesting.
- `antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` , access to all except `/api/register` , now response is 401 ?
- `antMatchers("/**).authenticated()` , everything returns 401 unauthorised

I wonder, all the `/api/quizzes` endpoints are under the `QuizController`, but the `/api/register` endpoint is under its own `@RestController` controller class. Have I missed an annotation? I can't see it, it's setup the same.

I know Spring isn't looking at my UserService as the `sout` message isn't printed. I did have this working at some point yesterday, it was fetching the `User` from the database table. I'm not sure what has changed.

Here's my UserService

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    static UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) {

        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        System.out.println("loadByUsername called");
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("loadUserByUsername called: user.isPresent() = true");
            return new MyUserDetails(user.get().getEmail(), user.get().getPassword());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User: " + email + " not found");
        }
    }

    public static void saveUserToDB(User user) {

        if (user.getPassword().length() < 5) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("password too short.");
        }

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("simon\\.aust@hotmail\\.com");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(user.getEmail());

        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("email not correct format");
        }

        userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);

}
```

MyUserDetails

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public MyUserDetails(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Edit 2;
With in-memory authentication I can authenticate with certain endpoints, but again not `/api/register`

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
           .passwordEncoder(org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .withUser("user1")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mistake which I caused myself a great deal of effort over.
Due to my naivety and overlooking where I was handling my exceptions, I was in fact returning a HTTP status with a custom exception on some if/else statement. That was fooling me into believing user authentication was not working when in fact it was.
Lesson of the day: Use breakpoints and debug :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/register/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/quizzes/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
```