# Expose end-point in Spring Security for unauthenticated users

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, unauthorized

I'm trying to expose an endpoint in a way that everyone can access it. That is, even a user who is not logged in can access.

I have the following setup:

My Config class:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.class)
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityAuthenticationConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    private static final String ANT_MATCHERS = "*/myEndPoint*";
           
    private static final String WEB_SECURITY_ANT_MATCHERS = "*/myEndPoint*";

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(ANT_MATCHERS)
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(WEB_SECURITY_ANT_MATCHERS);
    }
}
```

However, when I issue a request to the '*/myEndPoint*' end-point, I get a 401 Unauthorized
error. How I can avoid this? I have tried to reproduce the following issues but I have not succeeded:

[401 Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67650666/how-ant-matcher-works-in-spring-security)

[Configuring Springboot security, permitted path(s) not authorised 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171163/configuring-springboot-security-permitted-paths-not-authorised-401)

UPDATE:
The spring logs shows:

```
 Securing POST /v1/myEndPoint/3
 SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
 KeycloakDeployment   : Loaded URLs from http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/myRealm/.well-known/openid-configuration
 SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 Securing POST /error
 SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
 SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Comment: why havn't you enabled the spring security debug logs and checked the reason for your 401 Unauthorized error?

Comment: did you actually search google or read the spring documentation, before asking me? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users please do research before asking.

Comment: "How I can avoid this?" - by using a *correct* pattern ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)) also "Note: a pattern and a path must both be absolute or must both be relative in order for the two to match. Therefore, it is recommended that users of this implementation to sanitize patterns in order to prefix them with "/" as it makes sense in the context in which they're used."

Answer (score 0):

From shared config - HttpSecurity is actually properly configured.

It looks like issue is actually is in actual value of ANT_MATCHERS and WEB_SECURITY_ANT_MATCHERS variables - as they use single asterisk (*) symbol.

Ant matcher syntax (and also as Spring Security examples) expected wildcard to be represented not by 1 asterisk but by 2 (**) of them.

So, in your example, if endpoint that you want to publicly exposed is just '/my-endpoint' - you can change value of both variables to just "/my-endpoint".

Only if this URL is somehow prefixed or postfixed by some additional URL parts - only then you actually need to introduce additional matching. In that case you'll need to update it to "**/my-endpoint/**"